# Why is putting vim background color to comments and other special words?

Tags: vim

I'm using Vim for a while on Linux. Now I also want to use Vim on my Mac with iterm2, but I got ugly background color for comments and other commands, e.g. when I'm writing markdown. I tried differently colorschemes, but there are always this background color, which is not intended by the colorscheme

Example sonokai .md and .js file
[image]

Or the .vimrc file with everforest colorscheme
[image]

Can I disable/fix this behavior? For other syntax as well I see those background issues, not only for these examples.
Is it something special with MacOS?

Comment: As an additional comment. I'm running Vim in TMUX. I tried `:set t_ut=`, but this takes no effect

Without TMUX everything is working and I do not see the strange background

Answer (score 1):

This problem is ultimately caused by the way Vim detects terminal features.

In simple terms, Vim asks the terminal what escape sequences it uses for a specific feature and, if it doesn't get a response, falls back to some other ones that are known to work.

In this case, it asks for the italics escape sequences and [falls back](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/95707037afa1aeae4f3494dc623a721ceed7fc4e/src/term.c#L3386) to the worst possible known escape sequences: reverse video.

Since both colorschemes explicitly use italics for comments and Vim falls back to reverse video for italics, you get reverse video for comments.

That is actually a very old problem on macOS, where Vim has never been able to reliably detect italics support in terminal emulators despite it being available for a very long time. You can find various fixes online, this is the one I use:

```
" in .vimrc
" with ^[ obtained via <C-v><Esc>
set t_ZH=^[3m
set t_ZR=^[23m
```

The two commands above simply tell Vim the correct escape sequences for starting italics mode and stopping it.

The two colorschemes you mention happen to expose [an option to disable italics in comments](https://github.com/sainnhe/sonokai/blob/master/doc/sonokai.txt#L219). That is *one* way to handle the situation, other colorscheme authors deal with the issue differently. IMO, the only sane approach is to not use italics at all by default and eventually let the user enable the feature if they want.